# Expand objects by certain properties

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a array of objects like this that is output by a rest API, it is essentially a count of messages for every 15 minute interval for every hour per id.

```
[
   [
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 1, hour:1, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 2, hour:0, interval_1: 5 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 3},
       {id: 2, hour:1, interval_1: 3 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0}

   ]

]
```

How do I transform it to the below array using JavaScript?

```
[
   [
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_1: 2},
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_2: 1},
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_3: 3},
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 1, hour:1, interval_1: 2},
       {id: 1, hour:1, interval_2: 1},
       ...
       ...
   ]
]
```

Comment: What is the logic for the transformation?

Comment: What have you tried so far? SO is not your code-writing service really

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could separate the common keys and iterate the rest properies for mapping.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, hour: 0, interval_1: 2, interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0 }, { id: 1, hour: 1, interval_1: 2, interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0 }, { id: 2, hour: 0, interval_1: 5, interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 3 }, { id: 2, hour: 1, interval_1: 3, interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0 }],
    result = data.flatMap(({ id, hour, ...o }) =>
        Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => ({ id, hour, [k]: v }))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array#flatMap` and rest parameters to separate the properties.

```js
const arr = [
   [
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 1, hour:1, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 2, hour:0, interval_1: 5 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 3},
       {id: 2, hour:1, interval_1: 3 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0}

   ]
];
const res = arr.map(x => x.flatMap(({id,hour,...rest})=>
    Object.keys(rest).map(k => ({id,hour,[k]:rest[k]}))));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the array, and use `destructuring` to get the intervals, and get an array with the key and the value for each one of them.

Iterate over it with `Array.prototype.map()` and return a new array to the first `map()`

```js
const arr = [
   [
       {id: 1, hour:0, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 1, hour:1, interval_1: 2 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0},
       {id: 2, hour:0, interval_1: 5 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 3},
       {id: 2, hour:1, interval_1: 3 ,interval_2: 1, interval_3: 3, interval_4: 0}
   ]
]

const res = arr[0].map(({id, hour, ...rest}) => 
Object.entries(rest).map(([key, value]) => 
({ id, hour, [key]: value })));

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suggested `flatMap()` approach seems to be the most reasonable way, however, it may perform slower (especially, combined with `Object.entries()` as opposed to `Object.keys()`) than `reduce()` for large input arrays, so my solution would be something, like:

```js
const src= [{id:1,hour:0,interval_1:2,interval_2:1,interval_3:3,interval_4:0},{id:1,hour:1,interval_1:2,interval_2:1,interval_3:3,interval_4:0},{id:2,hour:0,interval_1:5,interval_2:1,interval_3:3,interval_4:3},{id:2,hour:1,interval_1:3,interval_2:1,interval_3:3,interval_4:0}],

      result = src.reduce((acc, {id, hour, ...intervals}) => {
        const entries = Object
                .keys(intervals)
                .map(key => 
                  ({id, hour, [key]: intervals[key]}))
        acc.push(...entries)
        return acc
      }, [])
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

If your actual input array consists of multiple arrays like `src` in my above example (which would make sense), you may wrap above `.reduce()` with function and apply that with `.map()` to every item of the input array.